# ODOO 12 menuitem not appears

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

Good day to all.
I am trying to add menu item to module Events with my custom module.
Also, in my module i add some models, so i pretty sure that module installed successfully.
In xml file i use this line to add menuitem

```
     <menuitem name="City Catalog" id="menu_event_city_catalog" parent="event.menu_event_mail_schedulers"/>
```

Menu item is created(i can find it on menu items menu), and parent is setted correct, but there is no changes in UI.
When i try to add menu item thru UI - it appears. 
I try this line with sequence and action attribute setted, but no effect.
Whould be grateful for any help, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try to add menu action**

```
<menuitem name="City Catalog" id="menu_event_city_catalog" parent="event.menu_event_mail_schedulers" action="your menu action"/>
```

Comment: Very strange. I already try this - and this have no effect. But i try this now - it's work. Maybe i miss something, but thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You must need to define **action** in menu to get reflation of your custom define menuitem.

Answer (score 0):

In odoo 12 you have to mention an action for a menuitem. Else it will not shown.
If it is a custom model, Please add security.